# How do I make a json file to be an asset instead of being bundled in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have a json file that I want to be part of an asset so I can also accessed it from the native code.  I don't want it to be bundled as that adds complexity on how the native code access the file.

Is there a way to exclude certain json files to be bundled, and still accessible as part of an asset?

Thanks!